# wordcloud words not fitting to mask

Tags: python, word-cloud

I'm attempting to create a wordcloud from a dataframe, where there is a column of words and a column for their respective frequencies. I've also downloaded an image that I want to use as a mask, for example: [cloud image](http://simpleicon.com/wp-content/uploads/cloud.png)

I can't get the wordcloud to fit to the mask - despite following the examples shown. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from wordcloud import WordCloud
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'word':['time', 'car', 'Peter\'s', 'sky', 
                           'something', 'computer', 'brain', 'plants',
                           'trees', 'Alien\'s', 'gun', 'eat'],
                   'freq':[24, 16, 16, 15,
                           14, 13, 12, 10,
                           9, 9, 5, 3]})

words = ' '.join(df['word'])

cloud_image = r"C:\Users\L\Documents\Python Scripts\cloud.png"

mask = np.array(Image.open(cloud_image))

wordcloud = WordCloud(max_words=2000,
                      width=1280, 
                      height=720,
                      mask=mask)

wordcloud.generate_from_frequencies()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
ax.axis("off")
ax.imshow(mask, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I just spent the past hour trying to get an particular image to work as a mask. The primary issue I was facing was that the image I wanted to use as my mask for my wordcloud did not have a white (RGB 255,255,255) background. The solution I ended-up with:

1. If your picture has a distinct background, use any online tool to remove the background color from your image. I used a site called "Background Burner" which made the background on my image transparent. However (as I found out), python's wordcloud treats a transparent background as black.
2. With the background-free image, use any online tool to change the background (which will likely be transparent) to white. I used a site called LunaPic to change my images .

The result is your original image with a white (RGB 255,255,255) background. wordcloud's mask will now treat your image as you expected!

Comment: Good that you found a solution. Just fyi the `WordCloud()` has an argument `background_color` that you can set to `'white'` for a background-free image (I think - it's been a while)

Comment: any idea on how to create a custom image?

Comment: This worked for me
`mask = np.array(Image.open("/content/transparent-background-logo.png")); mask[mask == 0] = 255`

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, it was just a problem with the size/type of the image. It worked with a different mask image (although I had previously tried two images before without success, hence the post).

Answer (score 1):

Some images should be adjusted for the process. Note only white point values for image is mask_out (other values are mask_in). The problem is that some of images are not suitable for masking. The reason is  that the color's np.array somewhat mismatches. To solve this, following can be done:
1.Creating mask object: (Please try with your own image as I couldn't upload:)

```
import numpy as np;
import pandas as pd;
from PIL import Image;
from wordcloud import WordCloud

mask = np.array(Image.open("filepath/picture.png"))
print(mask)
```

If the output values for white np.array is 255, then it is okay. But if it is 0 or probably other value, we have to change this to 255.

2.In the case of other values, the code for changing the values:
2-1. Create function for transforming (here our value = 0)

```
def transform_zeros(val):
    if val == 0: 
       return 255
    else:
       return val
```

2-2. Creating the same shaped np.array:

```
maskable_image = np.ndarray((mask.shape[0],mask.shape[1]), np.int32)
```

2-3. Transformation:

```
for i in range(len(mask)):
    maskable_image[i] = list(map(transform_zeros, mask[i]))
```

3.Checking:

```
print(maskable_image)
```

Then you can use this array for your mask.

```
mask = maskable_image
```

All this is copied and interpreted from this [link](https://www.holisticseo.digital/python-seo/word-cloud/), so check it if you find my attempted explanation unclear, as I just provided solution but don't understand that much about color arrays of image and its transformation.

Comment: `maskable_image[i] = list(map(transform_zeros, mask[i]))` This line no longer works. A much better and cleaner function would be `mask[mask == 0] = 255`